# Google Maps v3 keeps references to markers (zooming issue)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markers

I´m placing some markers on a Google Maps holding them in a global array. With a button click the markers should disappear from the map deleting them also from the array.

```
    // clear markers
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }

    // delete marker from markers array
    markers.length = 0;
    markers = [];
```

This works like a charm and the markers disappear from the map. In the next step i´m getting some new data via ajax-call, create markers again and add these markers in the markers array. New markers a visible on the map, but when zooming in/out the map suddenly the 'old' markers are visible again. So i have a mixture of the old and new markers.

Is this a Google Maps caching issue?
How to really remove the old markers from the map - map refreshing? 
Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

After writing this question i found the answer to this issue:
I also have an MarkerClusterer holding an reference to the markers array (and the markers). After clearing the MarkerClusterer all references to the old markers are gone. See this link:

[Any change in zoom level causes all my markers to re-appear on my Google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612360/any-change-in-zoom-level-causes-all-my-markers-to-re-appear-on-my-google-map/9619494#9619494)

Comment: The code you've posted is not sufficient to give an answer, please post more complete code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any change in zoom level causes all my markers to re-appear on my Google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612360/any-change-in-zoom-level-causes-all-my-markers-to-re-appear-on-my-google-map)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing :

```
markers.length = 0;
markers = [];
```

to:

```
markers = [];
markers = null;
```

then just before adding the new markers initialize the array again.